# Check if a string is null or empty, otherwise trim it

Tags: c#, null, string

I tried the following:

```
dummy.Title = ds1Question.Title.null ? "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

I was expecting to see something like `nullorempty` with intellisense but it seems there is nothing that can do that. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: With C# 6.0 we can now use null-conditional operators, like ds1Question.Title?.Trim()

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
 ds1Question.Title.null
```

You can have:

```
dummy.Title = ds1Question.Title == null ? "Dummy title"
                                        : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

Or use:

```
dummy.Title = (ds1Question.Title ?? "Dummy title").Trim();
```

That will perform unnecessary trimming to the default value, but it's simple.

These will only check for nullity though. To check for empty as well, you need to call [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx), which I'd do via an extra variable for sanity:

```
string title = ds1Question.Title;
dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? "Dummy title" : title.Trim();
```

Alternatively use [`IsNullOrWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) as per Marc's answer, to avoid having a title of "  " which isn't empty *until it's trimmed*.

Answer (score 13):

You could go a step futher of what Justin Harvey [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306994/402022) and implement an extension method (in a static class, of course) like this:

```
public static string TrimmedOrDefault(this string str, string def)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) //or if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    {
        // Hmm... what if def is null or empty?
        // Well, I guess that's what the caller wants.
        return def; 
    }
    else
    {
        return str.Trim();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
dummy.Title = ds1Question.Title.TrimmedOrDefault("Dummy title");
```

Comment: It won't let me edit just one character, but in case anyone still stumbles across this, the alternative should be "IsNullOrWhiteSpace" rather than "IsNullOrWhitespace"

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps:

```
dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds1Question.Title)
             ? "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

or

```
dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ds1Question.Title)
             ? "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds1Question.Title) ? 
                         "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some string extensions I use. I added one to do a safe trim. Hopefully someone will find these useful.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extensions for String
    /// </summary>
    public static class StringExtenions
    {
        public static string SafeTrim(this string input)
        {
            if (input.IsNotEmpty())
            {
                return input.Trim();
            }

            return input;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if a given string is empty.
        /// </summary>        
        public static bool IsEmpty(this string input)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if a given string is not empty.
        /// </summary>        
        public static bool IsNotEmpty(this string input)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts text to title case.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToTitleCase(this string input)
        {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;            
            TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

            return textInfo.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it via a string static method,

```
dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds1Question.Title) ? "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

If you want to be able to call it directly on the string instance, you could, of course, add an extensionmethod like this

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string str)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
}
```

Then you could use

```
ds1Question.Title.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Dummy title" : ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have almost got it. Try this:

```
dummy.Title = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds1Question.Title) ? 
    "Dummy title" : 
    ds1Question.Title.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

> dummy.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds1Question.Title) ? "Dummy title"
>   : ds1Question.Title.Trim();